# Expo sound, how to get the duration of a sound

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a sound object whose duration I need

```
this.soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
await this.soundObject.loadAsync(sound);
```

I've tried this, however the documentation says it only works for recordings.

```
this.soundObject.durationMillis
```

Is there something I'm overlooking? I can't seem to find a parameter for the duration.

Answer (score 8):

The duration is stored in the status, it needs a promise to access

```
 this.soundObject.getStatusAsync()
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result.durationMillis)
      })
      .catch(failureCallback);
```

Comment: I'm not simply getting value 1 for durationMillis even though the audio is getting played. This is Android. iOS is working fine

Comment: For those having the same trouble as me with `getStatusAsync`, I've noticed that in typescript the SoundObject status only returns back the `AVPlaybackStatus` interface, but it does include the same data as `AVPlaybackStatusSuccess` so using `as` fixes this:
```typescript
const statusSuccess = (await this.soundObject.getStatusAsync()) as AVPlaybackStatusSuccess`
```